# Calculating max $n$ so that $a$ has nth root over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algorithms, roots

Is there a fast way to find the maximal $n$ so that for $a \in \mathbb{Z_+} $,  $a^{1/n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

The only algorithm which I know is brute Force.

Greetings

Comment: Your title doesn't correspond to your question.

Comment: well kind of, thanks.

Comment: Better like this :)

Comment: Certainly $n$ must be less than $\tfrac{\ln a}{\ln 2}$, that narrows things down a bit.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime not dividing $a$ and $a\not\equiv1\pmod{p}$, then $p-1$ does not divide $n$.

Comment: so basically a "Sieve of Eratosthenes" typ of algorithm with special cases?

Comment: See Bernstein, Lenstra & Pila (2007), "[Detecting perfect powers by factoring into coprimes](http://cr.yp.to/lineartime/powers2-20060914-ams.pdf)".